# "windows.h" Not Found Using Eclipse SPARC bare-C Compiler

Tags: c, eclipse, mingw, uart, sparc

OK, so I am trying to connect an emulated (Through TSIM) LEON3 processor to a UART terminal. If I am not mistaken I believe I need to compile a C program to enable it to talk with a terminal as I am having difficulties doing it another way.
I found some source code for UART communication [here](https://github.com/waynix/SPinGW) and it all seems to be OK.
However, I am having issues compiling it using the SPARC Bare C Toolchain in Eclipse as it is saying that the windows.h file does not exist. Now I know it exists as I've compiled it successfully using the GCC Toolchain and can't find any similar cases on the web as to why this would be happening.

***Is there anyone out there who has had a similar problem or knows the solution?

Additionally, if you know me to be doing the wrong thing in regards to the LEON3 UART comms, please let me know and I will just leave.***

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

BCC is a **cross compiler** targeting standalone, LEON3- and LEON4-based environments.  As a cross compiler, its job is to build binaries for a different environment than the one in which it runs.

Relevant header files describe functions available to a program in its *runtime* (target) environment.  Build-environment libraries and their headers are irrelevant when cross compiling because the build and target environments differ.  BCC is correct to expose only the headers for the environment for which it compiles, and that environment does not provide Windows API functions.  If the code you're trying to build depends on the Windows API, then you'll need to modify it to remove that dependency, or else find something different.

On the other hand, I strongly suspect that you're going about this whole thing the wrong way.  In particular, when you say,

> I believe I need to compile a C program to enable it to talk with a terminal

it sounds like you think you're going to build some kind of helper program, but if that's your idea then either you're building it for the wrong environment or you have the wrong idea altogether.

If you want a Windows program that talks to the emulated machine, then you should be building that *as* a Windows program, and BCC doesn't do that.  In that case, you should be using MinGW's `gcc`, or another C compiler for the emulator's host environment.  Moreover, the host-side interface to the emulated environment's UART is an aspect of the emulator.  I haven't a clue what emulator you're using, but it might not present the host (Windows) side of that interface as a UART, and it might not require using the Windows API at all.

Or if you indeed do intend to build a program for the standalone LEON3 target environment, then you need to understand that when it runs, *it will be the only program that will be running in that environment*.  That's what "standalone" means -- no OS underneath, therefore no separate processes, and often not even multiple threads of execution.  Thus, you do not need a helper program; you just need a program.

[The BCC documentation](http://www.gaisler.com/doc/bcc.pdf) talks about the libraries available there, and in particular, it describes how in that environment, file I/O is allowed only on the standard input and output streams, which are mapped to UART A.  Thus, if you use BCC to build the program to run in the emulator, then you don't need to do anything special on that end to talk to the UART.  You just use stdio functions directed at `stdin` and `stdout`.

On the third hand, if you are running an actual operating system in your emulated environment, then to build programs that run on it you should be using either a native compiler for that environment, *in* that environment, or else a cross compiler targeting that hosted environment.  Either way, BCC is not such a compiler, but GCC might be.  Anyway, since Windows does not run on LEON3, it's safe to say that if this is what you're trying to do then you still need something that does not depend on the Windows API.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer. I still don't understand how I would access the data being sent / received through stdin/out? I'm using TSIM, and its not emulating (my bad) it is simulating the LEON3. As the host environment is windows, don't I need to know what COM port such data is going through?

Comment: @MrPhooky, "Simulating" and "emulating" mean close enough to the same thing, which my answer interprets as a virtual machine environment running on Windows / x86(_64) and presenting as LEON3 to whatever is inside.  That appears to be an accurate characterization of TSIM.  Code built by BCC and running on a bare TSIM machine would read from that machine's UART A by reading from `stdin`, and would write to it by writing to `stdout`.  Consult TSIM's documentation for how to access the *other* side of those channels.